# Comparing model fit of two Accelerated failure time (AFT) models in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis, goodness-of-fit, model-comparison

I use the `flexsurvreg` package/function to create a series of survival models (AFT Weibull). How can I compare the model fit of those models and, for example, suggest that a model is better than the control model?

I have tried several appraoches, such as `anova` or likelihood ratio tests (`lrtest` or `lrt.df`). However, I could not find any functions that can compare `flexsurvreg` models.

Alternatively, is there a way to transform the `flexsurvreg` objects to `survreg` or `flexsurv`model to make some of these functions work?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!